# Add Field Wrapping JSON - PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I have an array that I convert to json. But I want each object in the array to be wrapped by another field.

```
$Array =

Field1; Field2
-----------------
Value11; Value12
Value21; Value22
```

If I convert that array to JSON it looks like this:

```
Array
[
    {
        "Field1":  "Value11",
        "Field2":  "Value12"
    },
    {
        "Field1":  "Value21",
        "Field2":  "Value22"
    }
]
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Array
[
    {"NewWrapper":
        {
        "Field1":  "Value11",
        "Field2":  "Value12"
        }
    },
    {"NewWrapper":
        {
        "Field1":  "Value21",
        "Field2":  "Value22"
        }
    }
]
```

How do I either format the source or the json to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$Array | ForEach-Object { @{ NewWrapper=$_ } } | ConvertTo-Json
```

`@{ NewWrapper=$_ }` wraps each input object in a hashtable (`@{ ... }`) whose one and only entry, `NewWrapper`, is the input object (`$_`).

When `ConvertTo-Json` serializes this hashtable, it produces the desired output.

---

Complete example:

```
# Create sample input objects...
$Array = [pscustomobject] @{ Field1 = 'Value11'; Field2 = 'Value12' }, 
         [pscustomobject] @{ Field1 = 'Value21'; Field2 = 'Value12' }
# ... wrap them, and convert them to JSON.
$Array | ForEach-Object { @{ NewWrapper=$_ } } | ConvertTo-Json
```